# Django click confirm pop then call function in views.py

Tags: python, django, django-templates

I have a Django project ,now after clicking the url ,it will directly trigger the function in veiws.py.

But I now want to add a JavaScript or bootstrap pop window, inside the window there are 2 buttons ,cancel or confirm, only when confirm button has been clicked ,the function in views.py will be called ,otherwise if cancel is clicked, just return to pervious page.

url:

```
  path('wLoadr/', wLoadr_func, name='wLoadr_func'),
```

template html:

```
  <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="{% url 'wLoadr_func' %}">wLoadr</a></li>
```

views.py:

```
def wLoadr_func(request):
     # there are some wLoadr_func code here .....omit code
     return render(request, 'wLoadr/wLoadr_base.html')
```

pop window cancel and confirm button:

```
 <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" id='cancel'>Cancel</button>
 <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id='confirm'>Confirm</button>
```

Any friend can help ?

Answer (score 0):

It depends what Frontend framework you're using but you generally want to watch for the onclick event

As in:
`<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id='confirm' onclick="myFunction()">Confirm</button>`

Where myFunction() would look something like
`

```
function myFunction(){

    $.get('http://someurl.com/wLoadr/wLoadr_base.html',function(data) 
    {
    },'html');

}
```

`
I'm shooting from the hip here because I'm not a frontend dev but the main point I'm trying to get at is you want to listen for the click event on the button and then route to that page